# Ninject NamedScope Conditional Bindings

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-extensions

I am trying to make a conditional binding on whether or not I am inside a named scope.

My interface ILogger - using the default behaviour of the Ninject Logger extension we inject type-specific logger implementations into each class.  However, in one part of a system, we want a scope-wide logger instance, that is generated and disposed with the lifetime of the NamedScope...

At the moment (basically) we have this:

```
Bind<IEventViewModel>().To<EventViewModel>().DefinesNamedScope("Event").Named("Event");
Bind<IEventChild>().To<EventChild>().InNamedScope("Event");
Bind<Ninject.Extensions.Logging.ILogger>().To<EventWideLogger>().WhenAnyAnchestorNamed("Event").InEventScope();
```

However, what I really want is this:

```
Bind<IEventViewModel>().To<EventViewModel>().DefinesNamedScope("Event");
Bind<IEventChild>().To<EventChild>().InNamedScope("Event");
Bind<Ninject.Extensions.Logging.ILogger>().To<EventWideLogger>().WhenInNamedScope("Event").InEventScope();
```

As this would allow changes to the event scope definition object and keep the same behaviour.

I tried this but to no avail:

```
public static class WhenEx
{
    public static IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> WhenInNamedScoped<T>(this IBindingWhenSyntax<T> binding, string scopeName)
    {
        return binding.When(req => req.IsInNamedScope(scopeName));
    }

    public static bool IsInNamedScope(this IRequest req, string scopeName)
    {
        if (req.ParentContext != null && req.ParentContext.Parameters.OfType<NamedScopeParameter>().SingleOrDefault(parameter => parameter.Name == scopeName) != null)
            return true;

        return req.ParentRequest != null && req.ParentRequest.IsInNamedScope(scopeName);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't work. Can you post the ActivationException you get?

Comment: Quite right - for some unknown reason my initial attempt didn't work.  When I tried again it seemed to work as desired.  Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a prompt to retry from Remo (Thankyou), my code as described in the initial post does work:

```
Bind<IEventViewModel>().To<EventViewModel>().DefinesNamedScope("Event");
Bind<IEventChild>().To<EventChild>().InNamedScope("Event");
Bind<Ninject.Extensions.Logging.ILogger>().To<EventWideLogger>().WhenInNamedScope("Event").InNamedScope("Event");

public static class WhenEx
{
    public static IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> WhenInNamedScoped<T>(this IBindingWhenSyntax<T> binding, string scopeName)
    {
        return binding.When(req => req.IsInNamedScope(scopeName));
    }

    public static bool IsInNamedScope(this IRequest req, string scopeName)
    {
        if (req.ParentContext != null && req.ParentContext.Parameters.OfType<NamedScopeParameter>().SingleOrDefault(parameter => parameter.Name == scopeName) != null)
            return true;

        return req.ParentRequest != null && req.ParentRequest.IsInNamedScope(scopeName);
    }
}
```